# Are OTP for user registration supposed to store in session or datbase in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, amazon-web-services, one-time-password, user-registration

Are OTP supposed to store in session or database. Can anyone please tell the flow of OTP. As Far as i understood, when a user submits the necessary field the user details and the otp gets stored in database, and after register another form opens to enter otp and then the registration finally success. But I dont get the actual logic. To store the otp we need to store all the data in database, all the data gets stored (user info) only then we can verify the otp. I am using session but I am not sure if the code is correct,

```
    public function otpVerify(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'verification_code' => ['required', 'numeric'],
            'phone_number' => ['required', 'string'],
        ]);
        $otp = $request->session()->get('otp');
        $enteredOtp = $request->session()->get('otp');
        

    if ($otp == $enteredOtp) {
        $user = tap(User::where('phone_number', $data['phone_number']));
        // ->update(['isVerified' => true]);
        return success([
            $success,
            $otp
        ], __('User created successfully'));
 } else {
    return problem([], 500, 'OTP Doesnt Match');
 }


  public function register(RegisterUserRequest $request)
    {
        $user = new User($request->validated());
        $otp = rand(10000, 99999);
        $otp_expires_time = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(20);
    
        if (!env('APP_ENV') === 'local') {

            $sms = AWS::createClient('sns');

            $sms->publish([
                'Message' => 'Your OTP code is:' + $otp,
                'PhoneNumber' => $user->phone_number,
                'MessageAttributes' => [
                    'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType'  => [
                        'DataType'    => 'String',
                        'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
                    ]
                ],
            ]);
        } else {
            Log::channel('otplog')->info('Your OTP code is:'. $otp);
        }
        $status = $user->save();
        $user->roles()->attach($request->role_id);
        $user->brands()->attach($request->brand_id);
        $user->appliances()->attach($request->appliance_id);
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyAuthApp')->plainTextToken;
        $success['name'] =  $user->name;
        Session::put('OTP', $otp, 'expiry_time',$otp_expires_time);
        if ($status) {
            return success([
                $success,
                $otp_expires_time,
                $otp
            ], __('User created successfully'));
        } else {
            return problem([], 500, 'USER_REGISTER_FAIL');
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if a user wanted to verify the OTP from another device? This is not possible if you are using session (well, unless you are storing session in a database). I would suggest database. ALSO, storing plain text OTP anywhere is a security concern. You should treat it as you would any other password.

Comment: @user3532758I will go with the database then, the confusion is when i store the otp in database, all the information of user along with its otp gets stored, and when i verifyOTP, i fetch the orp from the database and verify, now what if the otp is incorrect, we have already stored the data in the database during register function??

Comment: Imo, there's nothing wrong with storing user information. During authentication, you can check if the OTP is verified (maybe via an `otp_verified_at` column). And ideally, you would have a mechanism to resend OTP to cater for wrongly entered OTPs. If you want to clean up unverified registrations in the future, you can use a cron or an admin function or any other mechanism of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store in database is a good option

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on this matter:

### **Session Storage**

Use session storage if you want the user to only be able to use that session on their requesting device real time. The moment they close their session, it will dispose. In this case, the duration of holding such OTP is dependent on the Session lifecycle. Use this method for real time verification processes on the app, e.g 2 Factor-Authentication.

---

### Database Storage

Database storage is great but can be rather an overkill for some scenarios, especially real time ones. Because you have to add records that will only last for few seconds and deleted again, in the case of 2FA. I would prefer using Database storage in cases where the OTP expiry has some "set" LifeSpan. For example, imagine a process where a user is filling in a registration form, where they have an option to save and continue later. In such scenarios, if part of the registration requires some OTP verification and the user can't verify real time, you normally give the user an OTP that expires after some lifespan e.g 3Hrs. So the user can come back later and use that OTP to continue with their registration. In this case, you delete the OTP from database as soon as the registration is completed.

Answer (score 0):

in session put method you did wrong you need to do like put array in session the way you are sending the expiration time you will not get the expiration time when you call you need to do like this

```js
Session::put([
'OTP' => $otp,
'expiry_time' => $otp_expires_time,
])
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can store OTP/any value to Storage using:**

```
Storage::put('otp', $otp);
```

**To Retrieve OTP/any value using:**

```
$storedOTP = Storage::get('otp');
```

**To Delete Storage Value:**

```
Storage::delete('otp');
```